# Django. Cancel button for form in admin site

Tags: django, django-admin, django-forms

Is there any functionality in admin site that allow to implement for every add/change form cancel button, that redirects me to list of that form objects. I mean some general solution for any form.

Comment: there are the breadcrumb links below the green banner that show "Home > App > Model > Object name" that can easily be used to go back to the objects list (dunno if you noticed it). Obviously that's not what are looking for though.

Comment: Yes, I saw these breadcrumb links - but this is not exactly what I want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add `admin/submit_line.html` in your project's `templates` directory. Use the code from [the default submit_line.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/submit_line.html), and add your cancel button. You can link it to just "../" to make it always just go up one level. Then do any necessary CSS styling to make it look right.

Comment: With this HTML Tag you even don't need CSS. Just add it to `submit_linkt.html`: `<a href="../"><input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel"></a>`

Comment: as @0xAffe says. But in changing may not work. You can change the button link to <a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}">. Then it goes to app change list.

Answer (score 1):

Create a file: `yourapp/templates/admin/submit_line.html`

I use Bootstrap, but you can change this easily

```
{% extends "admin/submit_line.html" %}

{% block submit-row %}

{{ block.super }}

<a href="../../" class="btn btn-secondary" style="color: white">Cancel</a>

{% endblock %}
```

Be sure that your application is above "admin" in INSTALLED_APPS.

Looks like this in German locale:

[image: cancel-button-in-django-admin]

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="{% url opts|admin_urlname:'changelist' %}"><input type="button" name="Cancel" value="Cancel"></a>
```

You can this line anywhere inside admin/submit_line.html